# Why does parseInt() sometimes return a string?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, parseint

This is a direct copy/paste from the javascript console on a new tab in chrome:

```
> var name = parseInt(prompt("enter a number"), 10);
undefined
> name
"77"
> var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"), 10);
undefined
> x
77
```

For some reason this only seems to happen if I use the variable name "name". It stays a string even on a regular assignment:

```
>name
"453"
>name = 77;
77
>name
"77"
```

Comment: Always test code in an isolated environment. The global environment is not isolated. Also, since you have identified that the issue is not with `parseInt`, the title is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [global variable `name` is a special variable in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) which represents the name of the current window and is always a string.

As a rule of thumb, it is generally a good idea to wrap scripts in [an IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so they have a local scope and you don't get conflicts with variables from other scripts and the browser. Doing so would avoid this issue.